# Spring WebFlux Configuration For FreeMarker Problems

Tags: spring-webflux

Following the [Spring WebFlux document](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-config), I set up a WebFlux for FreeMarker configuration s the following:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
    final FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver(
        "", ".ftl");
    registry.viewResolver(freeMarkerViewResolver);
  }

  @Bean
  public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    configurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("classpath:/templates");
    return configurer;
  }

 // @Override  <-- it causes a compile error
 public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
   configurer
        .setUseCaseSensitiveMatch(true)
        .setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
  }
}
```

The first compile error I run into is

```
method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
```

I guess that it is a documentation error. After commenting the override annotation out, I get a run time error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method httpHandler in org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.HttpHandlerAutoConfiguration$AnnotationConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxProperties' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxProperties' in your configuration.
```

I, however, am unable to find out how WebFluxProperties shall be defined. Please let me know if you have the information.

Comment: Are you using spring boot? Isn't it related with this bug? https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/20891

Comment: Thanks for the information. And yes, I use Spring Boot 2.3.0.M4. It is the same problem reported in the bug report. Which release the bug fix will be in?

Comment: 2.3.0.RC1. Should be released on next week. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/milestone/154?closed=1